# Span of standard 'basis vectors' in $l_\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $e_i=(0,...,0,1,0,...)\in l_\infty$ be the sequences with $1$ on the $i$-th position and all other entries $0$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

> How do I prove that the span of all $e_i$ is not dense in $l_\infty$?

What I thought:
The span of $e_i$ consists of all finite(?) linear combinations of $e_i$. So I thought the element $(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...)\in l_\infty$ is not the limit of any sequence of elements in the span, meaning the span is not dense.
How do I make this proof (if it is correct) more formal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that if $s$ is your sequence (or, more simply, the sequence of $1$s), then for every finite linear combination $v$ of standard basis vectors, you have
$\|s - v\|_{\infty} \geq 1$.

Comment: If I say $v=\sum_{i=1}^Na_ie_i$, do we then get $||s-v||_\infty=\sup\{|a_i-1|\}$?

Comment: Almost: If $v = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{i} e_{i}$, with $a_{i} = 0$ for $i > N$, the norm of the difference is just as you say.

Comment: But why does $\sup\{|a_i-1|\}\geq 1$ show denseness?

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of a metric space $(X, d)$, a point $s$ is in the closure of $A$ if and only if $$d(s, A) = \inf\{d(s, a) : a \in A\} = 0.$$Consequently, the particular sequence $s$ is not in the closure of $A := \operatorname{Span}(e_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$.